# Реализация работы двух сервоприводов постоянного вращения и одного на градус Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno

Есть 2 сервопривода постоянного вращения FS5113R (в программе - push и cut) 
И 1 сервопривод 180 градусов (в программе - bend)

Нужно сделать чтобы сначала серво push вращался 0.2 секунды, а потом останавливался
Потом серво deg поворачивался на 45 градусов и останавливался
Затем серво push вращался 0.3 секунды, а потом останавливался
И в конце серво cut вращался 0.1 секунды, а потом останавливался

Есть это, но не работает:

```
#include <Servo.h> 
Servo push;
Servo cut;
Servo bend;


void setup()
{

      push.attach(9);
      cut.attach(6);
      bend.attach(10);

}

void loop()
{
      int deg = 45;
      int onelen = 2;
      int twolen = 3;

      push.write(0);    //Проталкивание
      delay(onelen*100);//первой части
      push.write(90);   //на заданное расстояние

      bend.write(deg);//Сгибание детали
      delay(500);     //На заданный угол

      push.write(0);    //Проталкивание
      delay(twolen*100);//второй части
      push.write(90);   //на заданное расстояние

      cut.write(0); //
      delay(100);   //режем
      cut.write(90);//


}
```

Answer (score 4):

У вас Бендер один раз поворачивается на 45 градусов, потом никак не меняет своего положения. Я добавил в конце процедуры (после отрезания) возврат в исходное положение и увеличил все задержки, чтобы было понятно кто после кого жужжит (потом поменяете на нужные вам задержки).

Также есть подозрение, что каттер после отрезания должен еще вращаться в обратную сторону, но это не точно, т.к. не знаю что у вас за конструкция.

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo pusher;
Servo cutter;
Servo bender;

void setup()
{
      pusher.attach(9);
      cutter.attach(6);
      bender.attach(10);

      // В самом начале Бендера на всякий случай переводим в исходное положение
      bender.write(0);
}

void loop()
{
      int deg = 45;
      int onelen = 2;
      int twolen = 3;

      pusher.write(0); // Вращение пушера
      delay(1000);
      pusher.write(90); // Остановка пушера

      bender.write(deg); // Согнуть
      delay(500);

      pusher.write(0); // Вращение пушера
      delay(1000);
      pusher.write(90); // Остановка пушера

      cutter.write(0); // Вращение каттера
      delay(1000);
      cutter.write(90); // Остановка каттера

      bender.write(0); // Бендер в исходное положение
}
```

Вообще отладка не отличается от обычной отладки программ: поэтапно сначала заставляете одного вращаться как надо, потом второго поворачиваться как надо, а потом еще третьего вращаться как надо.

Демка (два полных цикла):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7e87.jpg